# How to select from two unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Hey I have a query where i want to get one row from two tables they are not joined as theres no logic for them to be, but i wish to collected the info from both tables in a single query if that is at all possible???

This is my current prepared statement:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id AS tid, item_name,price,user_name
FROM 
   users t1, items t2
WHERE
    t1.uid=$uid AND t2.id=$item_id AND t2.price <= t1.users_deposit
```

I made a quick pastie for the code: http://www.paste.to/MjU3NDE=

Currently when i try it and i `echo $row['tid'];` further into my script i get no output but I equally don't get undefined error. So im thinking the way i select two rows is the problem.

Comment: From what you posted, I don't see an error in you SQL statement.

Comment: This should work, but show the code where you are fetching the values.  Although it will work, this gets the cross product of the two tables according to values; it may make more sense to use a union or even two separate queries entirely

Comment: @ExplosionPills have added a pastie in the question :)

Comment: `t2.price <= t1.users_deposit` is a join condition.

Comment: no its not its a comparison.

Comment: But it's comparing between two tables. It's the old-style syntax for a join.

Comment: it would not make sense to join users cash to price because then if the user had more money than price.. the join would fail as they would not be equal

Comment: That's the point of his query. It only returns the row if the user can afford to buy the item.

Comment: i know - i wrote it lol im not sure comparisons are same as joins so to speak =/ joins are to do with finding a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never define `$row`.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

Comment: ah balls. i hate it when i miss something like that !! Thanks !